# Empty cFileName when calling FindNextFile in a labwindows cvi application

Tags: c, windows, 64-bit, cvi

I'm currently working on a cvi application where I need to retrieve every .wav files of the current build directory. To do so in C, I'm using windows built-in function FindFirstFIle and FindNextFile in the following function :

```
int listingWavFileNameInDirectory( char projectDirectory[MAX_PATHNAME_LEN], int numberOfWavFile, char **ListOfWavFile)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA searchingFile;
    HANDLE handleFind = NULL;
    char workingPath[2048];

    sprintf(workingPath, "%s\\*.wav*", projectDirectory);

    if( (handleFind = FindFirstFile(workingPath, &searchingFile)) != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        ListOfWavFile[0] = searchingFile.cFileName;
        i = 1;
        while(FindNextFile(handleFind, &searchingFile)
        { 
            ListOfWavFile[i] = searchingFile.cFileName;
            i++;
        }
        if( !FindClose(handleFind))
            return GetLastError();

        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        return GetLastError();
    }
}
```

This function works fine for the first wav file ( ListOfWavFile[0] has the right string), but not for other file name which are get through FindNextFile and are include ListOfWavFile[i]. ListOfWavFile[i] is actually an empty string. I just don't understand why. This is my call to the previous functions :

```
GetProjectDir(projectDirectory);
numberOfWavFile = countingWavFileInDirectory(projectDirectory);
listOfWavFile = malloc(numberOfWavFile * sizeof(char *));
for(int i = 0; i < numberOfWavFile; i++)
{
    listOfWavFile[i] = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
}
listingWavFileNameInDirectory(projectDirectory, numberOfWavFile, listOfWavFile);
```

I'm on windows 7 64-bits and my application is compiled as a 64-bits application. I try to use Wow64DisableWow64FsRedirection like said in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95956/findnextfile-fails-on-64-bit-windows), but it doesn't work for me.

Any ideas ?

Comment: You need to `strcpy` these filenames, not just use `=`.

Comment: With few exceptions, strings (character arrays) in C cannot be assigned values using the `=` operator.  As ooga has said, you must use a function.  Most commonly `strcpy()` is used in scenarios like yours.

Answer (score 1):

***In LabWindows/CVI, you must***

```
#include <ansi_c.h>  //header collector for ansi C libraries included in CVI environment
```

for the following suggestions to work...

You must use a ***[string copy or concatenation function](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/)*** to assign values to strings, with few exceptions.

In C, other than at initialization, you cannot use the `=` operator to assign values to a `char` array (`char *a;`, `char a[];`).

***For example***, while something like:

```
char *a = {"this is an initialization string"};
//or
char a[] = {"this is an initialization string"};
```

Is perfectly ok...

***This is not***:

```
char a[80] = {0}; //okay
char b[] = {"this is a string"}; //okay still

a = b;  //Not OKAY
```

***Use strcpy instead:***

```
strcpy(a, b);  //the correct way
```

***In your code*** therefore, make the following changes:
(assuming that `ListOfWavFile` is a `char **` that has been properly initialized and allocated memory)

```
strcpy(ListOfWavFile[0], searchingFile.cFileName);//HERE
i = 1;
while(FindNextFile(handleFind, &searchingFile)) //note the addition of the last ")"
{ 
    strcpy(ListOfWavFile[i], searchingFile.cFileName);//And HERE
    i++;
}
```

***Turn your compile warnings up*** to maximum.
In CVI it looks like this (or similar, depending on version):
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the C lesson, that's what append when you learn on the job ! I'll accept your answer, but I have one question left : do you have an explication on why is it working for the first time `ListOfWavFile[0] = searchingFile.cFileName;` but not in the second one ?

Comment: @NessyW. - I am not sure how you have declared ListOfWavFile.  Depending on how, may offer some explanation in terms of ***[undefined behavior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)***.  It could have something to do with the line: `while(FindNextFile(handleFind, &searchingFile)`  (you need another `)` ).  Without seeing more I cannot say for sure.  But turn your compile warning up to full.  (See picture in edit)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @ooga's comment about `strcpy()`, there is a missing ) in this line

```
while(FindNextFile(handleFind, &searchingFile)
```

And you should be range-checking `i` against the argument `numberOfWavFile` which you haven't used. OK, you found out the number of .wav files first, but that may have changed by the time you parse the folder. *Assume nothing when it comes to array usage.* So the above line should read

```
while (FindNextFile(handleFind, &searchingFile) && i < numberOfWavFile)
```